# Python automatically adds singlequotes around float value in List

Tags: python, pytest, stdout, assertion

I struggle with Python(3.9.7) automatically adding singlequotes around a float-value, which leads to a failing assertion.

My goal is to use pytest to assert an expected output of a parsing-function. The parser takes a json-object (shortened code sample below) and returns a list of *Signal* objects. I copied the print-out from           `logging.debug(f"{signal_list}")` inside the parsing function,  and assigned it to *expected_result* in my test-function:

```
#Arrange   
message = json.dumps({"data":{"name":"battery_volt","alias":"Volt","unit":"volt","value":12.0,"time":1644587969}})
        
expected_result = [Signal(id=None, name='battery_volt', description=None, value=12.0, type=None, unit='volt', time='2022-02-11T13:59:29')]
print(expected_result)
p = Parser(message)

#Act   
result = p.parse_message()
        
#Assert  
assert result == expected_result
```

Irritatingly, `pytest -vv` throws an AssertionError:

```
E         Full diff:
E         -  [Signal(id=None, name='battery_volt', description=None, value='12.0', type=None, unit='volt', time='2022-02-11T13:59:29')]
E         ?                                                                -    -
E         +  [Signal(id=None, name='battery_volt', description=None, value=12.0, type=None, unit='volt', time='2022-02-11T13:59:29')]
```

The upper line seems to be the value of *expected_result*, because `print(expected_result)`
also adds the singlequotes around the 12.0

I assume the copied output from `logging.debug(f"{signal_list}")` isn't the same as the real value of result. I tried typecasting *expected_result* as list, str()-converting both *result* and *expected_result* inside the test, but *expected_result* always has `'12.0'` and *result* has `12.0`.

I desperatly need a hint how to do this kind of assertion the correct way.

EDIT:
Here is the parsing function:

```
 def parse_message(self):
        message = json.loads(self.message)
        #logging.debug(f"message is: {message}")       
        message_data = message.get('data', {})
        parsed_data = []

        try:
            device = message_data.get('device', None)
            if device is not None:
                vehicle = self.parse_vehicle(device)
                parsed_data.append(vehicle)
            else:
                logging.error("'device' was None!")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
        
        signals = []
            
        try:
            data = message_data.get('data', None)
            if data is not None:
                signals = self.parse_signals(data)
            gps = message_data.get('gps', None)
            if gps is not None:
                gps_signal = self.parse_gps(gps)
                signals.append(gps_signal)
                parsed_data.append(signals)           
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
                 
        return parsed_data 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_logging()
    message = json.dumps({"consumerid":redacted,"data":{"device":{"time":1644587969,"imei":"redacted","man_id":redacted,"car_id":999,"vin":"redacted"},"data":[{"name":"battery_volt","alias":"Volt","unit":"volt","value":12.0,"time":1644587969}],"gps":{"lat":51.437515,"lon":6.9281199,"dir":252,"alt":88,"sat":19,"time":1644587969}},"event":"redacted","itemid":redacted,"itemtype":1,"senderip":"redacted"})
    p = Parser(message)
    signal_list = p.parse_message() 
    logging.debug(f"{signal_list}")
```

Please note that the passed json-objects are more complex than the code-sample in the original post.

```
class Signal(BaseModel):
    id: int = None
    name: str = None
    description: str = None
    value: str = None
    type: str = None
    unit: str = None
    time: str = None
```

EDIT2 - Assignment of Signal.value happens here:

```
def parse_signals(self, data):
        signals = []
        #logging.debug(f"data is : {data}")
        for data_object in data:
            signal = Signal()
            try:
                signal.name = data_object.get('name', None)
                #get dtc-count value as seperate return-element, needed by the controller to handle dtc-codes
                if signal.name == 'dtc_count':      
                    self.dtc_count == data_object.get('value', None)   
                signal.description = data_object.get('description', None)
                signal.value = data_object.get('value', None)
                signal.time = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data_object.get('time', None)).isoformat()
                signal.unit = data_object.get('unit', None)
                if signal.unit == "dtc":
                    signal.type = "1" 
                if signal.name is not None:
                    signals.append(signal)
                    #logging.debug(signal.__dict__)                
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"While parsing signal {data_object}, the following error occured: {e}")
                        
        return signals
```

When parse_message is called as `__name__ == "main":`, the testcode beneath outputs `value=12.0`

Comment: Can you share the code for `Parser` the inconsistency is probably there.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni, I don't think so, the stdout of logging.debug(f"{signal_list}") had no singlequotes, neither has the return value of parsed_data, which can be seen in the pytest Full diff that I posted.

Comment: If I get a downvote for a question, I would appreciate a corresponding comment with the reason. I am happy to edit or give additional information.

Comment: If `expected_result` always has the quotes and the parsed value does not, it would seem that the `Signal(...)` constructor forces `value` to be a string (which seems consistent with the type hint in the class declaration), while the parser does not. You have showed us neither of these, so it's hard to be certain. Figure out where `value` gets assigned, and how.

Comment: @TurePålsson, I added the function where the value is assigned to Signal.value. It should be cast as str, but printing/logging the Object to Console, there are no quotes. That's fine with me, but the problem emerges later. After I assign the copied output to *expected_result* (first codeblock), you can see, there are no quotes. When this var is printed then or used in the assertion, the quotes appear, and I don't know why.

Comment: SOLVED does not belong in the question. You mark your question solved only by adding or accepting an answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, will remember that. Just wanted to mark it, because I can only accept my own answer 2 daysfrom now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out python type hints don't enforce like I expected:

When parse_message is called by way of `__name__ == "main":`, the testcode beneath outputs `value=12.0` Apparently, despite the type-hint :str for Signal.value, 12.0 was assigned as float. When I tried to sys.stdout.write(signal_list), I got a TypeError.

I now simply str()-convert in parse_signals() like this

```
signal.value = str(data_object.get('value', None))
```

resulting in having my value in single quotes consistently.